# Flutter : Can't access data passed from another screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I'm trying to build 2  screens one contains a list of products and the second has product details, I'm using Firebase to store data and so I fetch the data from Firestore in the first screen and it all works perfectly.
However, in the second screen, I pass product data correctly using `Navigator` but I cannot use that data in my UI.

#### Here is the code for my second screen:

[image: [!https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT1c9.png]]

As you can see I cannot use the name variable in my widget tree, I've seen videos on youtube and I found that some people use state management to solve this problem, but for my case I just want to pass data and display it.

Comment: provide the first screen code too from where you pass the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've passed the data is correct but the way you've accessed the data isn't.

Whenever you try to access the variables of a Class in its state, you do that using `widget`. So, to access the name or other variables, just do as follows:

```
widget.name
```

Additionally, if the only purpose is to pass and display the data, then, there's no need of a `StatefulWidget`, use a `StatelessWidget` instead.

Comment: To add to the above answer. If you use `StatelessWidget` instead, then your way of referring to the passed-in parameter is correct. For `StatefulWidget` arguments, you need to prefix each with `widget.`.

Answer (score 0):

A [State] object's configuration is the corresponding [StatefulWidget] instance. This property is initialized by the framework before calling [initState]. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new widget with the same [runtimeType] and [Widget.key] as the current configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the new widget and then call [didUpdateWidget], passing the old configuration as an argument.

For that you can use `widget.key`, this will work fine for you.